# Does Python Pandas have a way to specify a column that counts each individual occurrence of a combination of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with 22 columns that deal with building assessments, however, I am only focused on two specific columns. These two columns are a numeric building ID and an assessment phase that indicates which phase a corresponding building ID is in. Basically, what I would like to do is count the occurrence of a combination of values across these two columns and store those counts in an ordinal column. Details are below:

```
  Building ID   | Assessment Phase
-----------------------------------
  001                Phase 1
  002                Phase 2
  002                Phase 2
  003                Phase 3
  003                Phase 2
  003                Phase 3
  004                  Unk
  004                Phase 1
  005                Phase 2
```

You'll notice there are repeating IDs and assessments that look the same. I would like to have a cumulative row count of each like occurrence grouped by Building ID and Assessment Phase. It should look something like this:

```
  Building ID   | Assessment Phase | Bldg_Phs_Ord
--------------------------------------------------
  001                Phase 1              1
  002                Phase 2              1
  002                Phase 2              2
  003                Phase 3              1
  003                Phase 3              2
  003                Phase 3              3
  004                  Unk                1         
  004                Phase 1              1
  005                Phase 2              1
```

As can be seen there are individual counts of each combination. Some combinations repeat a few times in which each following combination is placed on its own row.

What I have tried is this to test that it was coming out correctly:

```
test_cnt = bldg_df.groupby(['Building ID', 'Assessment Phase']).size().to_frame('COUNT').sort_values(by=['Building ID']).reset_index()
```

Unfortunately, this aggregates the combinations together whenever there is more than one repeating combination.

```
     Building ID   | Assessment Phase | COUNT
--------------------------------------------------
  001                Phase 1              1
  002                Phase 2              2
  003                Phase 3              3
  004                  Unk                1         
  004                Phase 1              1
  005                Phase 2              1
```

What should I add so that it returns each individual, cumulative row count?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you are looking for `cumcount`:

```
df["count"] = df.groupby(['Building ID', 'Assessment Phase']).cumcount()+1

print (df)

   Building ID Assessment Phase  count
0            1          Phase 1      1
1            2          Phase 2      1
2            2          Phase 2      2
3            3          Phase 3      1
4            3          Phase 3      2
5            3          Phase 3      3
6            4              Unk      1
7            4          Phase 1      1
8            5          Phase 2      1
```

Comment: this is indeed what I was looking for. The other answers led me to doing more research to discover the ```cumcount()``` method and also caused me to realize I should have included the word "cumulative" in my original post. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assume `df` is Your input dataframe, try:

```
df['COUNT'] = df.groupby(['Building ID', 'Assessment Phase']).cumcount().add(1)
```

`cumcount` does not reduce rows.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is close to what I am looking for in that it doesn't aggregate the rows together. However, I am also looking for an individual row count of each recurring combination, such as my example in what I was looking for in my original post.

Comment: ok, just changed count to cumcount, but column name 'COUNT' was a bit misleading:-)

Answer (score 0):

First, create the data frame:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''  Building ID    Assessment Phase
001                Phase 1
002                Phase 2
002                Phase 2
003                Phase 3
003                Phase 2
003                Phase 3
004                  Unk
004                Phase 1
005                Phase 2

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
'''
```

Second, create a helper column called 'counter' (0 for unknown assessment phase, and 1 otherwise):

```
df['counter'] = 1
mask = df['Assessment Phase'] == 'Unk'
df.loc[mask, 'counter'] = 0
```

Third, group by building ID, and apply the cumsum (cumulative sum) function to the counter column.  Then manually update the 'unknown' rows.

```
df['Bldg_Phs_Ord'] = df.groupby('Building ID')['counter'].cumsum()
df.loc[mask, 'Bldg_Phs_Ord'] = 1
print(df)

   Building ID Assessment Phase  counter  Bldg_Phs_Ord
0            1          Phase 1        1             1
1            2          Phase 2        1             1
2            2          Phase 2        1             2
3            3          Phase 3        1             1
4            3          Phase 2        1             2
5            3          Phase 3        1             3
6            4              Unk        0             1
7            4          Phase 1        1             1
8            5          Phase 2        1             1
```

I don't know how to avoid the special handling for the 'Unk' Assessment Phases.  And `cumsum()` is sensitive to the initial order of the data frame.

Comment: thanks. This is a good breakdown and pointed me in the right direction. Your method ```cumsum()``` led me to another method that seems to do the trick.: ```cumcount()```. That method starts at "0", so you can just add a "+1" to start the count at 1. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for expaining cumcount!  I've used groupby / rank in the past, but cumcount expresses the intent more clearly.